# Add values to a tensor element based on its position in pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, addition, tensor

In pytorch, I want to add values to elements in the tensor based on their position. For example consider,

```
Input = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0])
```

Between several offsets of the Input array, `Offsets = [0,5,10,15,20]`, I want to add different values, `ValuesToAdd = [10,100,1000,10000]`

I expect the output to be

```
Output = torch.tensor([11,12,13,14,15,106,107,108,109,100,1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,10006,10007,10008,10009,10000])
```

Here, between indices `Offsets[i]` and `Offsets[i+1]` in Input array, `ValuesToAdd[i]` is added. For example, for indices `10,11,12,13` and `14` (`Offsets[2] = 10` to `Offsets[3]=15`) in Input array, `1000` (`ValuesToAdd[2]`) is added.

How can I achieve this? Instead of looping over Offsets array, I am looking for a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [torch.repeat_interleave](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.repeat_interleave.html)

```
Offsets = torch.tensor(Offsets)
shifts = Offsets[1:] - Offsets[:-1]
output = Input.clone()
output[Offsets[0]:Offsets[-1]] += torch.tensor(ValuesToAdd).repeat_interleave(shifts)
print(torch.all(output == Output))
# True
```